# How can I recover my content homepage in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I found out that I deleted accidentaly my homepage mainpage (/page/homepage) in Odoo CMS and founded that I deleted all my main page stuff. Is there a way to restore it, recover it?

Thnx.

Comment: you create your database backup or not??

Comment: I installed Odoo Bitnami stack and dont make any backup.